Retrieve only the drive letter, (without the colon)
I spent a few hours trying to figure this out. Please kindly provide a little help:)
I'm using this to capture the drive letter:
FOR /F "tokens=2 usebackq delims==" %i IN (`wmic volume where "Label='System Reserved'" get DriveLetter /format:list`) DO @echo %i

Works perfectly, but it returns driveletter:
I need the : to be gone,
so I can pass the alphabet character only as a variable into diskpart
This is what I have:
SET SOURCE=SystemReserved
FOR /F "tokens=2 usebackq delims==" %i IN (`wmic volume where "Label='System Reserved'" get DriveLetter /format:list`) DO set SystemReserved=%1

IF "%SystemReserved%"=="" GOTO notfound
Diskpart remove letter=$Source%
:notfound
Exit

But that darn : is killing me :)

Just a three line batch file: @Set "SystemReserved=", @For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Volume Where "Label='System Reserved'" Get DriveLetter /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do @Set "SystemReserved=%%G" and @If Defined SystemReserved %SystemRoot%\System32\diskpart.exe Remove letter=%SystemReserved:~,1%. Obviously this will need to be run with elevation.

I haven't worked in a programming language that hasn't allowed you to substring or split apart another variable.  The help for that syntax is in the SET command. Open a cmd prompt and type set /?.

Here are some answers to compliment my initial comment. In them I added the additional security of ensuring that there is a drive letter allocated to the volume with that label, and that it is identified as a system volume too.
If you wanted to continue using diskpart.exe, then it could be achieved in a single line, by using the unwanted colon as a delimiter:
For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^": %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Volume Where "Not DriveLetter Is NULL And Label='System Reserved' And SystemVolume=TRUE" Get DriveLetter /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\diskpart.exe Remove letter=%G

As you have now changed to using mountvol.exe you could simply adjust to exclude the : delimiter:
For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Volume Where "Not DriveLetter Is NULL And Label='System Reserved' And SystemVolume=TRUE" Get DriveLetter /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\mountvol.exe %G /d

Note: The above answers use direct entry in cmd, as did your own. If you wish to run them from a batch-file instead they would look more like these:
DiskPart:
@For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^": %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Volume Where "Not DriveLetter Is NULL And Label='System Reserved' And SystemVolume=TRUE" Get DriveLetter /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\diskpart.exe Remove letter=%%G

MountVol:
@For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Volume Where "Not DriveLetter Is NULL And Label='System Reserved' And SystemVolume=TRUE" Get DriveLetter /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\mountvol.exe %%G /d


Thank you for the guidance. I'll test this

Thank you all, really nice to see willing folks to help.
I decided to go this route.
Tested and joy ---
FOR /F "tokens=2 usebackq delims==" %i IN (`wmic volume where "Label='System Reserved'" get DriveLetter /format:list`) DO set SystemReserved=%i

SET SOURCE=SystemReserved
FOR /F "tokens=2 usebackq delims==" %i IN (`wmic volume where "Label='System Reserved'" get DriveLetter /format:list`) DO set SystemReserved=%i

IF "%SOURCE%"=="" GOTO notfound
Mountvol %SystemReserved% /d

:notfound

exit /b 0


You just need a substring of %SystemReserved%
source=%SystemReserved:~0,1%
diskpart remove letter=%source%

You may need to
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

before the script and
endlocal

at the end of the script

why remove the colon, when you can get the value without the colon in the first place? Just add : to the delimiters:
FOR /F "tokens=2 usebackq delims=:=" %i in (`wmic volume where "Label='System Reserved'" get DriveLetter /value`) do  set "SystemReserved=%i"

(Note: for use in a batch script, use %%i instead of %i. (all instances))
(usage of /value instead of /format:list is personal preference - both are perfectly fine)
